# Как ставить Okular на Windows?

Tags: windows

Если она Open Source и доступна на Windows, то как её устанавливать? Почему бы разработчикам просто не выложить дистрибутив на оф. сайте?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/92aji5/kde_okular_on_windows/

Comment: Могу порекомендовать `STDViewer`.

Comment: `Почему бы разработчикам просто не выложить дистрибутив на оф. сайте?` — потому что не хотят с этим возиться. СПО на то и свободное, что исходники открыты, а дальше по желанию. Вот если нашёлся сторонний человек, готовый собирать Windows-дистрибутивы и поддерживать их, то соответственно установщик и доступен на его сайте (см. комментарий don Rumata выше).

Comment: Таки есть под винду и прям можно поставить автоматом: https://chocolatey.org/packages/okular/

Comment: https://binary-factory.kde.org/view/Windows%2064-bit/job/Okular_Release_win64/